# Cassandra datacollection from newts in OpenNMS Horizon

Tags: cassandra, opennms

I have a cassandra cluster of 3 nodes setup with replication set to 2 and I am trying to make it collect the performance data from OpenNMS I have setup newts schema too, but not able to figure out how should I make it collect data from OpenNMS? any suggestions.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Please share the code or configurations file you have used so far.

Comment: I have just done the basic configuration for the cluster in cassandra.yaml file and made newts from the OpenNMS Server to create schema on the nodes in cassandra cluster.

Comment: Please share the configuration; it isn't enough to provide a short hand description.

Answer (score 0):

Have you followed [this guide](http://docs.opennms.org/opennms/releases/18.0.0/guide-install/guide-install.html#gi-configure-opennms) for setting up Cassandra with the Newts schema and configuring OpenNMS Horizon?